# How to use as many arguments as provided?

Tags: coffeescript

I have a function which takes any number of arguments and must call two other functions with exactly the same arguments in the same order. I tried like this :

```
broadcast = (socket, command, args...) ->
  socket.emit command, args
  socket.broadcast.to('room').emit command, args
```

This works if `args` is just an argument but how can I make it work if there are several arguments ?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on coffeescript, but wouldn't it be `socket.broadcast.to('room').emit command, args...` ? I guess this is something in the lines of what you want? https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1020

Comment: Seems to be working really well ! Thank you. Maybe you can put this as an answer so I can award you the points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on coffeescript, but wouldn't it be

```
socket.broadcast.to('room').emit command, args...
```

I guess this is something in the lines of what you want? http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1020

Answer (score 0):

Make args to be an array of whatever your arguments are. And then pass that array around.